# Running only one Perl script instance by cron

Tags: perl, cron

I need to run Perl script by cron periodically (~every 3-5 minutes). I want to ensure that only one Perl script instance will be running in a time, so next cycle won't start until the previous one is finished. Could/Should that be achieved by some built-in functionality of cron, Perl or I need to handle it at script level?

I am quite new to Perl and cron, so help and general recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Which platform are you talking about? *nix?

Comment: http://blog.booking.com/highlander-daemons-without-daemons.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have always had good luck using [File::NFSLock](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::NFSLock) to get an exclusive lock on the script itself.

```
use Fcntl qw(LOCK_EX LOCK_NB);
use File::NFSLock;

# Try to get an exclusive lock on myself.
my $lock = File::NFSLock->new($0, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB);
die "$0 is already running!\n" unless $lock;
```

This is sort of the same as the other lock file suggestions, except I don't have to do anything except attempt to get the lock.

Comment: Thanks! I like it most, since it's very compact and not writing anything to file.

Comment: It's still using a lock file. If the script is foo.pl, then it uses foo.pl.NFSLock by default. So you need write permission to the directory.

Comment: I like this solution because it is simple and only requires a common perl module.  If you're using it to prevent cron job overlaps, you probably want it to exit without fuss so you don't get endless cron emails when you run it every minute :-)  use this instead of die:  `exit 0 unless $lock;`

Comment: To install is "apt-get install libfile-nfslock-perl"

Comment: This solution worked great for me for two reasons. (1) If I call File::NFSLlock->new() with "LOCK_EX" instead of "LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB", then the lock request becomes blocking and waits until the lock is obtained. This provides basic unsorted "poor-man's queueing". (2) The solution is not broken even if the perl script holding the lock terminates abruptly (e.g. kill -9). Although the lock file still exists, it is no longer NFS-locked. The next call to File::NFSLlock->new() will NFS-lock the file, then properly delete the file upon completion.

Answer (score 13):

The [Sys::RunAlone](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::RunAlone) module does what you want very nicely.  Just add

```
  use Sys::RunAlone;
```

near the top of your code.

Comment: +1 after reading this in the ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS: (Thanks to) Booking.com for using this heavily in production and allowing me to improve this module.

Comment: This is such an awesome package. Save me a lot of work!

Answer (score 12):

Use [File::Pid](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Pid) to store the script's pid in a file, which the script should check for at the start, and abort if found. You can remove the pidfile when the script is done, but it's not truly necessary, as you can simply check later to see if that process id is still alive (which will also account for the cases when your script aborts unexpectedly):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Pid;

my $pidfile = File::Pid->new({file => /var/run/myscript});
exit if $pidfile->running();

$pidfile->write();

# ... rest of script...

# end of script
$pidfile->remove();
exit;
```

Comment: I was surprised to find no flock calls in its source!

Comment: @gbacon: feel free to submit a patch :)

Comment: I would not recommend this answer. You have a race condition (calling write after running). It's probably never going to be an issue in a cron job, but better avoided still as there are better answers (see accepted one).

Answer (score 4):

A typical approach is for each process to open and lock a certain file. Then the process reads the process ID contained in the file.

If a process with that ID is running, the latecomer exits quietly. Otherwise, the new winner writes its process ID (`$$` in Perl) to the pidfile, closes the handle (which releases the lock), and goes about its business.

Example implementation below:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Fcntl qw/ :DEFAULT :flock :seek /;

my $PIDFILE = "/tmp/my-program.pid";
sub take_lock {
  sysopen my $fh, $PIDFILE, O_RDWR | O_CREAT or die "$0: open $PIDFILE: $!";
  flock $fh => LOCK_EX                       or die "$0: flock $PIDFILE: $!";

  my $pid = <$fh>;
  if (defined $pid) {
    chomp $pid;
    if (kill 0 => $pid) {
      close $fh;
      exit 1;
    }
  }
  else {
    die "$0: readline $PIDFILE: $!" if $!;
  }

  sysseek  $fh, 0, SEEK_SET or die "$0: sysseek $PIDFILE: $!";
  truncate $fh, 0           or die "$0: truncate $PIDFILE: $!";
  print    $fh "$$\n"       or die "$0: print $PIDFILE: $!";
  close    $fh              or die "$0: close: $!";
}

take_lock;
print "$0: [$$] running...\n";
sleep 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have always used this - small and simple - no dependancy on any module and works both Windows + Linux.

```
use Fcntl ':flock';                    

### Check to make sure there is only one instance ###
open SELF, "< $0" or die("Cannot run two instances of this program");
unless ( flock SELF, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB ) {
    print "You cannot run two instances of this program , a process is still running";
    exit 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK perl has no such thing builtin. You could easily create a temporary file, when you start your application and delete it, when your script is done.

Comment: Sorry, I foresee big troubles if something goes wrong (machine restart) and file is not deleted...

Comment: Fair to say, but if the machine is restarted while your script is running, you'll probably face troubles anyway (unless the script does something extremely trivial).

Comment: Restart can happen during the script run. The script is using db transactions, so I suppose it'll "survive" restart preserving data integrity.

Comment: than write pid into that file and check if a process with that pid is still running.

Answer (score -2):

Given the frequency I would normally write a daemon (server) that nicely waits idly between job runs (i.e. `sleep()`) rather than try to use cron for fairly fine-grained access.

If necessary, on Unix / Linux systems you could run it from `/etc/inittab` (or replacement) to ensure that it always running, and is automatically restarted in the process is killed or dies.

**Added**: (and some irrelevant stuff removed)

The always present (running, but mostly idle) daemon approach has the benefit of eliminating the possibility of concurrent instances of the script being being started by cron automatically.

However it does mean you are responsible for managing the timing correctly, such as in the case of there is an overlap (i.e. a previous run is still running, while a new *trigger* occurs). This may help you decide whether to use a forking daemon or non-forking design. Threads don't provide any advantage in this scenario, so there is no need to consider their usage.

This does not completely eliminate the possibility of multiple processes running, but that a common problem with many daemons. The typical solution is to use a semaphore such as a mutually-exclusive lock on a file, to prevent a second instance from being run. The file-lock is automatically forgotten when the process ends, so in the case of abnormal termination (e.g. power failure) there is no clean-up necessary of the lock itself.

An approach using Fcntl module, and using a Perl `sysopen` with a `O_EXCL` flag (or `O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL`) was [given by Greg Bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2232970/83348). The only differences I would make are combine exclusive locking into the sysopen call (i.e. use the flags I've suggested), and remove the then redundant `flock` call. Oh, and I would follow the UNIX (& Linux FHS) file-system and naming conventions of `/var/run/daemonname.pid`.

Another approach would be to use djb's [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or [similar](https://serverfault.com/questions/192302/alternative-to-daemontools-djbtools-to-supervise-unix-processes) to "daemonize" the task.

Comment: Running a daemon doesn't eliminate the multiple running scripts issue .. it's easy for someone or something to accidentally try to start up a second daemon.  You still need a PID file to deal with that issue.