# How to write perl sript that can't be run simultaneously

Tags: perl

I have a small Perl script. I want to change it to make it impossible to run several copies of this script in the same time.

What is the best way to do it? Maybe there is a way to solve this task with the modules that are shipped with perl and without installing modules from CPAN?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232860/running-only-one-perl-script-instance-by-cron

Comment: Thank you! I've decided to use `Sys::RunAlone`