# Perl flock: prevent multiple invocation based on variable

Tags: perl, locking, flock

I would like to prevent multiple invocation of a Perl script based on a variable or command-line arguments. Extending [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27434074/2035207):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;
my ( $foo, $bar );
GetOptions (
    "foo" => \$foo,
    "bar" => \$bar,
    ) || die "usage: $0 [ -foo | -bar ]\n";

use Fcntl ':flock';
flock(DATA, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB) or die "There can be only one! [$0]";

say STDOUT (($foo?"foo":$bar?"bar":"nobody")." sleeps");
sleep(2);

# mandatory, flocking depends on DATA file handle
__DATA__
```

How can I lock `app.pl -foo` and `app.pl -bar` independently?

Comment: `__DATA__` is a file handle of the perl script you are running - which is the same independent of the command line argument,. If you want different  locks depending on the command line argument you have to construct a filename based on the argument, open it to get the file handle and lock this instead of `__DATA__`.

Comment: To use the same mechanism, you would need to lock two different files. But you could use a different mechanism, such as writing the arguments to a file and removing them when the program ends. (But then you have to worry about stale locks.)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've come up so far. Kindly suggest if there's a better answer:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{HUP}=\&sigHandler;  # 1
$SIG{INT}=\&sigHandler;  # 2
$SIG{QUIT}=\&sigHandler; # 3
$SIG{KILL}=\&sigHandler; # 9 - CANNOT BE CAUGHT
$SIG{TERM}=\&sigHandler; # 15
$SIG{STOP}=\&sigHandler; # 17 - CANNOT BE CAUGHT

use Getopt::Long;
my ( $foo, $bar );
GetOptions (
    "foo" => \$foo,
    "bar" => \$bar,
    ) || die "usage: $0 [ -foo | -bar ]\n";


use Fcntl qw(:flock);

sub lock {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    flock($fh, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB) or die "There can only be one! [$0]: $!\n";
}

sub unlock {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    flock($fh, LOCK_UN) or die "Cannot unlock file - $!\n";
}

my $file = "$ENV{'HOME'}/".($foo?"foo":$bar?"bar":"nobody");
open(my $fh, '>', $file) or die "Can't open $file: $!";

sub sigHandler {
    say STDERR "$0: Program interrupted by '@_'. Terminating...";
    unlink ($file);
    unlock ($fh);
    exit 1;
}

lock ($fh);
say STDOUT (($foo?"foo":$bar?"bar":"nobody")." sleeps");
sleep(5);
unlink ($file);
unlock ($fh);
exit 0;
```

Comment: Thank you @ikegami. I shall remove them.

Comment: in your error handler : you should remove the file from disk only if your process holds the lock on it, or not remove the file from disk at all. Otherwise, there is a small time window (from after the `$file = ...` assignment until the return-or-die of the `unlock()` function) during which your program will delete the lockfile on `Ctrl+C` even if it doesn't hold the lock on it.

Answer (score 1):

I added a `singleton()` method to [IPC::Shareable](https://metacpan.org/dist/IPC-Shareable) that does this using shared memory. Here's a simple example. It uses the argument sent into the script as the 'glue' to lock the script run.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use IPC::Shareable;

die "Need arg" if ! @ARGV;

my $arg = $ARGV[0];

my $lock = $arg;
my $warn = 1;

IPC::Shareable->singleton($lock, $warn);

for (1..10) {
    print "$_\n";
    sleep 1;
}
```

Running `perl script.pl foo` will lock with `foo`. If you run the command again while the first instance is still running, you'll get `Process ID 1105497 exited due to exclusive shared memory collision`. If you run it with `perl script.pl bar`, it'll succeed.

It'd be wise to use a lock glue string more complex than just the argument (perhaps the name of the script concatenated with the argument value), but I digress.

I also wrote [Script::Singleton](https://metacpan.org/dist/Script-Singleton) which locks out any second instance of a script from being run, but it's implemented at compile time, so it can't decipher based on argument. It's script-level only.